# How can i transpose my table?

Tags: visualforce

I am iterating two account's records dynamically to merge them using radio button,but i ain't getting them as column Like-

```
 AccountId         0012800000vRtPM-----------0012800000vRtPb
   Account Name---------Aman------------------ Aman
   RecordType----------- Group--------------- Group
```

So how can i solve it ?

**Visualforce page** (this is my second vf page)

```
<apex:page controller="objectController" applyHtmlTag="true">
<apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock title="Show records">


    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!chooseTwolst}" var="c">

        <apex:repeat value="{!fieldNames}" var="FieldLable">  
       <tr>
           <td><apex:column value="{!c[FieldLable]}"/> </td>
      </tr>
        </apex:repeat>    

     </apex:pageBlockTable>


   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller :**

```
 public class objectController {

    public String searchCategory { get; set; }
    public Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    public String selectedObject {get; set;}

    public String selectedField {get; set;}

    public String newName{get;set;}

    public List<sObject> chooseTwolst{get;set;}

    public List<sObject> selectedsObject{get;set;}

    public List<Wrapper> acclist{get;set;} 

    public List<String> fieldNames{get;set;}

    Integer k=1,var=0;

    Public objectController()
    {   
        selectedObject = 'Contact';
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getObjectNames() 
    {
        List<SelectOption> objNames = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<String> entities = new List<String>(schemaMap.keySet());
        entities.sort();
        for(String name : entities)
        {
            objNames.add(new SelectOption(name,name));
        }
        return objNames;
     }



     public void findData()
      {
          String newQuery = 'Select ';
            newQuery += generateQuery(selectedObject);
            newQuery += ' from '+selectedObject+' where Name = '+'\''+newName+'\'';
            System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+newQuery);
            List<sObject> lstvalues = Database.query(newQuery);
           acclist = new List<Wrapper>();
             for(sObject ac : lstvalues)
               {  
                  acclist.add(new Wrapper(ac));
                }
          }


           public String generateQuery(String sObjectAPI){
        //Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
           Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(sObjectAPI).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
           String expr = '';
            for(String fieldName : fieldMap.keyset()) {
                expr += fieldName + ', ';
            }
            expr = expr.subString(0, expr.length() - 2);
            return expr;
   }   



  public PageReference ProcessSelected()
   {
     //if(count == 0){
     selectedsObject = new List<sObject>();
     //selectedAccount1 = new List<Account>();
    for(Wrapper accou : acclist)
    {
     if(accou.chkbox == true)
      {  
       selectedsObject.add(accou.sob1);
        // i++;
       }

     }
     chooseTwo();
     //count++;
      return Page.DynamicObjectHandlerVf1;

  }



  public PageReference chooseTwo()
    {
    System.debug('===============================================calling a function');
     if(selectedsObject.size()>1){
        chooseTwolst = new List<sObject>();
     var = 2*k-2;
     chooseTwolst.clear();
     if(var < selectedsObject.size()){
     chooseTwolst.add(selectedsObject[var]);
     chooseTwolst.add(selectedsObject[var+1]);
       ObjectFields();
       System.debug('==============================================='+chooseTwolst.size());

     }

    }
    else
    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'You should have select atleast two  Accounts.'));
      k++;
     return null;

   }



     public void ObjectFields() 
     {

           // Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
            Schema.SObjectType ObjectSchema = schemaMap.get(selectedObject);
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = ObjectSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            fieldNames = new List<String>(fieldMap.keySet());


      }


    public class Wrapper
   {
    public boolean chkbox{get;set;}
    public sObject sob1{get;set;}
    public Wrapper(sObject a)
     {
      sob1 = a;
      chkbox = false;
      }
    }     
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<table> 
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectAPI.FieldSet.FieldSetName}" var="f">   
        <tr>
        <td><strong>{!f.Label} :</strong></td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!List}" var="l">
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(AND(f.Type != 'date',f.Type != 'datetime'),true,false)}">
                        <td class="tb-header-list-body">{!l[f.fieldPath]}</td>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(OR(f.Type == 'date',f.Type == 'datetime'),true,false)}">
                        <td class="tb-header-list-body">
                            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,M/d/yyyy hh:mm a}">
                                <apex:param value="{!l[f.fieldPath]}"/>
                            </apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tr>
    </repeat>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Amit.Is that solution solve your problem?